# Looking for a word that describes something that is complex and overwhelming yet elegant?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes something that is both complex (in the sense that it may overwhelm at first sight) and elegant at the same time.

The first word I could think of was "monstrosity" but I feel that carries too much of a negative connotation.

Specifically, this relates to describing my reaction to a vehicle.

I have attached the picture below to give an example.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you think *elegant* means.

Comment: In general, *elegant* means "surprising simplicity" (in the sense applied by mathematicians). I would not characterize that vehicle as possessing that quality.

Comment: I was referring to elegance in terms of being "graceful and stylish." This, of course, is obviously subjective though.

Comment: I might just say, "Wow! That is certainly one "*well-appointed*" vehicle..."

Comment: "Sophisticated" , both 1) complex or intricate, as a system, process, piece of machinery and 2) having or showing refinement.

Comment: *marvelous*? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few single word suggestions:

***Ornate***

> *adjective*
>
> **Elaborately or highly decorated.**

***Sophisticated***

> *adjective*
>
> (of a machine, system, or technique) **developed to a high degree of complexity.**

***Majestic***

> *adjective*
>
> **Having or showing impressive beauty or scale.**

***Intricate***

> *adjective*
>
> **Very complicated or detailed.**

All of these words usually have a positive connotation of elegance and also of overwhelming complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I don't think there exists a single noun in English that embodies what you seek. Mr. Bron explains elegance well. The closest example I could think of to a small selection of vocabulary you seek is beautiful complexity.

Comment: Do you mean "*beautiful complexity*" or "*beautifully complex*"?

Comment: Curse this autocorrect. Beautiful complexity

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but I can come up with **"gracefully massive"**

> - [**graceful**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gracefully) - (adj) characterized by elegance or beauty of form, manner, movement, or speech; elegant:
> - [**massive**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/massive) -  very large and heavy

note: I can see no elegance or grace in that picture.  As a matter of fact the vehicle doesn't seem to fit any definition of elegance.